# execute first emitted element of reactive chain

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am doing a spring webflux reactive code

```
 .flatMap(r -> save1)
 .flatMapMany(r -> save2) //save a flux of elements
 .flatMap(r -> save3) //need r.getId
 .subscribe();
```

I want to control the emission of events and only save 3 event for first emitted element of the previous chain (flatmapMany) instead of N times.

So in resume, i need to save N elements and catch the first save and ignore the others. I need to result of save2 to pass argument for save3 method.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly you can use `.next()` to "convert" `Flux` into `Mono` by taking the first emitted element and then cancel the subscription.

```
 .flatMap(r -> save1)
 .flatMapMany(r -> save2) //save a flux of elements
 .next()
 .flatMap(r -> save3) //need r.getId
```

Here is a test for the above flow that shows that only "2.1" was handled in `save3`

```
@Test
void testFlow() {
    var flow = Mono.just("1")
            .flatMap(r -> save1(r))
            .flatMapMany(r -> save2(r))
            .next()
            .flatMap(r -> save3(r));

    StepVerifier.create(flow)
            .expectNext("2.1")
            .verifyComplete();
}
```

where

```
private Mono<String> save3(String r) {
    return Mono.just(r);
}

private Flux<String> save2(String r) {
    return Flux.just("2.1", "2.2", "2.3");
}

private Mono<String> save1(String r) {
    return Mono.just(r);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

but without a subscribe() it will not execute the entire chain (save1, save2) , right or i'm doing confusion?

Imagine that i have 3 mono objects to save on save2

```
-> save 2.1 
-> save 2.2
-> save 2.3
```

after 2.1 save operation (first element) -> get response and save only once

```
-> save 3
```

instead of save 3 times

```
-> save 3
-> save 3
-> save 3
```

So ... the idea is stop chain propagation to not duplicate saved objects in DB.

Comment: This is exactly wear next does and of course nothing happens without subscription but usually framework like webflux will subscribe

Comment: updated the answer with the test